# '(Int) -> Int' is not convertible to 'Int'

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Hi I put some code from The Swift Programming Language book into a playground and I'm getting the following error message.
`('(Int) -> Int' is not convertible to 'Int')`
What is going on?
Thanks for help

```
func stepForward (input: Int) -> Int {
     return input + 1
}
func stepBackward (input: Int) -> Int {
     return input - 1
}
func chooseStepFunction (backwards: Bool) -> Int {
     return backwards ? stepBackward : stepForward
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a function when `chooseStepFunction` expects a *Int* to be returned instead. You need to change the return type from `Int` to `(Int) -> Int`

```
func chooseStepFunction (backwards: Bool) -> (Int) -> Int {
     return backwards ? stepBackward : stepForward
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you try to return a function, it should be

```
func chooseStepFunction(backwards: Bool) -> (Int) -> Int {
    return backwards ? stepBackward : stepForward
}
```

`chooseStepFunction` returns a function that takes an int and returns an int.